# How does this array size macro/function template work?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, c++98

I've come came across this snippet in the article [PVS-Studio vs Chromium](https://pvs-studio.com/en/blog/posts/cpp/a0074/)

```
template <typename T, size_t N>  
char (&ArraySizeHelper(T (&array)[N]))[N];  
#define arraysize(array) (sizeof(ArraySizeHelper(array)))
```

I've seen other templates to do the same thing, like [Use templates to get an array's size and end address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073276/use-templates-to-get-an-arrays-size-and-end-address).

I understand those, but I've been having difficulty with this one.

Comment: What in particular are you having difficulty with? There are lots of distinct elements of C++ at work here.

Comment: dupe. Also see the explanation at the bottom of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437150/can-someone-explain-this-template-code-that-gives-me-the-size-of-an-array/437178#437178 (that's not the dupe, I'm too lazy to search it now).

Comment: Link to the dupe or it didn't happen :)  I couldn't find the dupe either, otherwise I wouldn't have posted.

Comment: and the real question why not to use `std::extent` instead of this ugly macro?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magic arguments in function templates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384107/magic-arguments-in-function-templates)

Comment: not sure why they want to complicate things..  Templates must be instantiated..  Macros dont and disappear into constants.. == sizeof(array)/Sizeof(element).  #define ARRAY_SIZE(A)  (sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0]))

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The function template is named `ArraySizeHelper`, for a function that takes one argument, a reference to a `T [N]`, and returns a reference to a `char [N]`.

The macro passes your object (let's say it's `X obj[M]`) as the argument.  The compiler infers that `T == X` and `N == M`.  So it declares a function with a return type of `char (&)[M]`.  The macro then wraps this return value with `sizeof`, so it's really doing `sizeof(char [M])`, which is `M`.

If you give it a non-array type (e.g. a `T *`), then the template parameter inference will fail.

As @Alf points out below, the advantage of this hybrid template-macro system over the alternative template-only approach is that this gives you a compile-time constant.

Comment: I'll just add about the purpose, namely to get the array size as a compile time constant (which in turn can be used to specify the size of a raw array). As I recall it was a Russian who first came up with this variation. Unfortunately I don't recall the name.

Comment: So, I take it, that the function is declared but not defined? The syntax is hard for me to parse.

Comment: @Alf this is 2004, pretty early: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/the1/archive/2004/05/07/128242.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I think it was the syntax for returning char (&)[M] that was throwing me.  C/C++ array syntax is awful.

Comment: Johannes, that article is a perfect explanation.  Thanks.

Comment: `std::extent<decltype(array)>::value` is a compile-time constant, so what's the advantage?

Comment: @Gene Bushuyev: Basically that you can use this code in any compiler that follows the 98 standard, but you cannot use your approach unless the compiler implements C++0x features (at the very least `decltype` and the `extent` type trait.

Answer (score 8):

This isn't the nicest way of doing it, but since you're asking: The return type of the template function `ArraySizeHelper` is `char[N]`, where the argument of the function is a (reference to an) array of size N of type `T`. Template argument deduction instantiates this template with the matching number N, and so `sizeof(char[N])` is just N, which is what you get.

A nicer version could be written as follows. (You need C++11 for `constexpr`; if you omit it, this will not be a constant expression.)

```
template <typename T, size_t N> constexpr size_t array_size(const T (&)[N]) { return N; }
```

Usage:

```
int x[20];
array_size(x); // == 20
```

---

**Update:** If you are in C++11, here is another solution that gives a constexpr, thanks to decltype:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T> struct array_traits;
template <typename T, unsigned int N> struct array_traits<T[N]>
{
   static const unsigned int size = N;
   typedef std::decay<T>::type type;
};

// Usage:
int x[20];
array_traits<decltype(x)>::size; // == 20
```

If you are in C++17, you can also use [`std::size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) to get the size of an array.

Comment: so out of curiosity, what do you feel the nicest way of doing it is?

Comment: @Jalf: Updated. No compiler macros!

Comment: Trouble with that is that it's not constexpr, unlike the macro.

Comment: @DeadMG: True. Could we somehow wrap this in a way that doesn't need macros? More importantly, do the two compute different assembler output?

Comment: @Kerrek SB: the macro is only to simplify the syntax when using it. It's not *necessary* in any way (And the constexpr version pretty much by definition generates *no* assembler output

Comment: Hm, at `-O0` my version does generate some code, but at `-O2` the two produce the same result... yeah, the constexpr is morally better, though I find my oneliner syntactically more pleasant. Take your pick...

Comment: @Kerrek: yeah, yours is easily optimized away, but you're not guaranteed that this will happen, and more importantly, you can't use it in situations where a compile-time constant is expected, like you can with `sizeof`, or with the version the OP asked about. So that's definitely the more powerful version, but for most common uses, your "simple" version does the trick just fine (and it avoids macros)

Comment: @Jalf: I suppose, but in which situation would a compile-time constant be expected where you only have access to the object rather than its type? It's a good point, but I've been struggling to find examples for its use. If you have the type already, we can make a proper typetrait class anyway...

Comment: @Kerrek: in which case is `sizeof` necessary *at all* under those constraints? It is useful because the type might be a template parameter, so it is not explicitly stated, or because we don't want to duplicate the type information (which would be fragile if we later decide to change the size of the array). If you have the type, you don't need *any* kind of sizeof, and yet sizeof is useful. (And if you don't have the type, then no sizeof implementation will work, because that can only occur if the array has decayed to a pointer.)

Comment: But suppose you want to create a second array of the same size. The second array's size must be specified as a constant expression, so a `sizeof` trick like this would be a convenient way to do it, without having to type out the size information twice

Comment: @jalf: I added a C++0x version using `decltype` that's hopefully both constexpr _and_ macro free!

Comment: Just put `constexpr` before your first function template, and `array_size(x)` will be a constant expression too in C++0x.

Comment: @Johannes: Excellent! Does that mean that this is a completely equivalent solution to the macro now? [Update:] I just tested: Taken by itself at `-O0`, the assembly is different, but if I use `array_size(x)` as a template parameter, I get the exact same assembly as if I took the macro version.

Answer (score 4):

[This blog on MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/the1/archive/2004/05/07/128242.aspx) precisely describes how it works. Very interesting story. Take a look at it.