# Weird constexpr argument in code

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to understand the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

// constexpr functions use recursion rather than iteration
constexpr int factorial(int n)
{
    return n <= 1 ? 1 : (n * factorial(n-1));
}

// literal class
class conststr {
    const char * p;
    std::size_t sz;
 public:
    template<std::size_t N>
    constexpr conststr(const char(&a)[N]) : p(a), sz(N-1) {}
    // constexpr functions signal errors by throwing exceptions from operator ?:
    constexpr char operator[](std::size_t n) const {
        return n < sz ? p[n] : throw std::out_of_range("");
    }
    constexpr std::size_t size() const { return sz; }
};

constexpr std::size_t countlower(conststr s, std::size_t n = 0,
                                             std::size_t c = 0) {
    return n == s.size() ? c :
           s[n] >= 'a' && s[n] <= 'z' ? countlower(s, n+1, c+1) :
           countlower(s, n+1, c);
}

// output function that requires a compile-time constant, for testing
template<int n> struct constN {
    constN() { std::cout << n << '\n'; }
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "4! = " ;
    constN<factorial(4)> out1; // computed at compile time

    volatile int k = 8; // disallow optimization using volatile
    std::cout << k << "! = " << factorial(k) << '\n'; // computed at run time

    std::cout << "Number of lowercase letters in \"Hello, world!\" is ";
    constN<countlower("Hello, world!")> out2; // implicitly converted to conststr
}
```

What is the parameter

```
const char(&a)[N]
```

? I don't understand it.. seems like a reference to an array.. and what's the point in passing it to a constexpr constructor?

Comment: Yes, it is a reference to an array of fixed size. And because its size is defined by a template, it has the result of defining a (constexpr) constructor for each size of array that you might pass (with the end result that `sz` is set to the constant size of the array you passed). So that's fine, but whether `constexpr` is actually *valid* for constructors is something I'm not sure about.

Comment: probably duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376000/how-does-this-array-size-template-work

Comment: OK, some quick searches tell me that `constexpr` constructors are indeed valid. In effect they allow the constructor to be called at compile time, leaving just something which behaves like `thing a={0,1,2}` behind, pretty much as you'd expect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parameter `const char(&a)[N]` *is* a reference to an array.

The point of it is that it allows the compiler to deduce the length of the array. Without the reference, `const char a[N]` as parameter would be equivalent to `const char* a` which doesn't allow the template parameter `N` to be deduced.

Comment: That is not the only point. The array is immutable. Plain `char(&a)[N]` wouldn't do here.

Comment: Nor would `char* a`. But that's an orthogonal issue, and there's no indication that David Kermin had any problems with the `const`.

Comment: It is not an orthogonal issue. The `constexprs` wouldn't work with a mutable, fixed size array.

Comment: The deduction of `N` is orthogonal to the whole thing being `constexpr`. It would work exactly the same way on a non-`constexpr` template.

Answer (score 2):

This is (along with the `template<std::size_t N>` part), a way to get the size of a constant string, so you can do:

```
conststr hello("Hello, World!");
```

and later:

```
size_t s = hello.size();
```