# Why am I getting this error? Could not convert {lb, ub} from <brace-enclosed initializer list> to float(**)(float*, int)

Tags: c++

I have a function prototype that's returning this error. I'm also getting a warning for extended list being for `-std=c++11` or `-std=gnu++11`

```
float lb(float* data, int y);
float ub (float* data, int y);

float operation(Stats* ptr, float* data, int y, float(*fp[])(float*, int) = {lb, ub});
```

Comment: I'm unable to copy/paste so I rushed, but its a float

Comment: What about [edit]? ;-)

Comment: Btw. it seems to work with a "helper" array: [**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d9fdbf2c152cf270).

Comment: If I remember right (plain C) arrays cannot be created as temporaries. That might be the reason why it doesn't work without helper array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass a temporary array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42332229/how-to-pass-a-temporary-array)

Comment: @Scheff [I was just thinking the same thing](https://ideone.com/u5DfyP).

Comment: @Scheff Whenever I actually make the function definition a default argument for parameter 4 is given. Is the definition not supposed to match the prototype when using a helper array?

Comment: I don't get your comment. (Not sure, whether I understood it right.) A default argument is given in declaration (prototype) only. (It must be visible for the source where the function is called.) It may not be repeated in the function definition. (That should result in a compiler error.) Btw. default arguments are applied at "call" time - i.e. at run-time. Hence, even function calls can be used to provide default arguments.

Comment: ...with a scarying function returning a pointer to function pointers: [**Test on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2327ed62ce3c25ca) ;-)

Comment: array of functioning pointers.. ithis looks like a  puzzle (to figure out what really that data type is)  or C era legacy XD

Answer (score 2):

Your array decays to a pointer inside a function declaration (if you don't take it by reference). What you can do is wrap your default value in a constant, like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/rX8CVt) (note that you lose the array size with this approach if you don't pass it as an extra parameter):

```
using OperationType = float(*)(float*, int);
constexpr OperationType DefaultOperations[] = {lb, ub};

float operation(Stats* ptr, float* data, int y, const OperationType* fp = DefaultOperations);
```

If you always know the the size of your array at compile time you can use `std::array` like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/XW5iFC):

```
using OperationType = float(*)(float*, int);

template <std::size_t Size>
float operation(Stats* ptr, float* data, int y, std::array<OperationType, Size> fp = {lb, ub});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are treating the `[]` as a declaration of an array. But in function parameters it only declares a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
typedef float(*fp[])(float*, int);
float operation(Stats* ptr, float* data, int y, fp pfp = (fp) {lb, ub});
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure whether this is standard conform. g++ seems to have concerns as well: [**Test on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2fa2287d680a359f) - `warning: ISO C++ forbids compound-literals`

Comment: What about `-pedantic`? Btw. it's g++ 9.2 on coliru.

Comment: Oh I used `-Wall` but did not use `-pedantic`

Comment: This is not C++ standard-conform. It works in C, but not C++.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this ugly syntax you could actually use a vector of typedef'd std::functions. It would look better and compile just fine.

```
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

float lb(float* data, int y) { return 0; }
float ub(float* data, int y) { return 0; }

typedef std::function<float (float*, int)> Func;

float operation(void* ptr, float* data, int y, std::vector<Func> funcs = { lb, ub }) { return 0;  } 
/* didn't declare stats, so I use void here instead */

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    operation(nullptr, nullptr, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::function` is much more general than a function pointer, and this generality is [not for free](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5057382/673852).

Comment: Of course. Still, unless the code is VERY performance-critical, using std::functions is fine.

Comment: I even used them for my ESP32 (which is a microcontroller) projects, and it was fast enough for me. Something like `std::map<packet_type, std::function<void(packet)>> network_packet_handler`.